# How to make a div block with margins be flexible without going behind browser window

Tags: flexibility, css

I'm trying to make the following div flexible

```
div {
min-width: 500px;
max-width: 1000px;
width:100%;
height: 400px;
margin-left:100px
}
```

If I remove the margin left everything works fine, but with the margin, when I start resizing the browser window, the box goes behind the browser window and only then starts being resized. How do I solve this issue? I tried a wrapper, tried resetting box-sizing, tried with different positionings but nothing seems to work, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `width: calc(100vw-100px);` or `calc(100% - 100px)`. This sets the width of the div to **Veiwport width - Margin**

Also **remove `max-width: 1000px;` and `min-width: 500px;`**

```
div {
 width: calc(100%-100px);
 height: 400px;
 margin-left:100px
}
```

```css
div {
     width: calc(100%-100px); /*or `width: calc(100vw-100px);`*/
     height: 400px;
     margin-left:100px;
     background-color:pink;
    }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Didn't know about this function in css, but vh seems to work fine too. Yet, is there a cleaner way to accomplish this for browsers like IE <=9? And this seems to be an experimental technology right now.